# Does iOS kill my iPad App if not used by user for a long time?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

Suppose I am using one App (no other App is active). Now I lock the iPad by simply clicking the lock button or may be I put it in background mode and put my iPad somewhere.

After what amount of time, the App will get killed automatically by system if I don't use that App? Is there any specification by Apple or we cannot say anything that App will launch from scratch in some scenarios.

Note that in any scenario, I don't kill my App manually.

Comment: No, there is no specification. iOS will decide "by itself" when to terminate background apps

Comment: The term that you’ll see in the device console is that the OS may “jettison” the suspended app at its discretion. So, you’ll want to be able to gracefully handle this (e.g. [state restoration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches) or what have you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS generally (at least in current versions) doesn't kill apps after some arbitrary time. It kills them when it needs to free up resources. Since modern iPads have quite a bit of memory, that means that apps can stay in the background for a very long time depending on how the iPad is used. As Andreas notes, however, there are no promises about that.

Comment: Thanks Rob Napier. You are absolutely right. I tried it practically and when I opened my iPad after 14 hours, the App was active (not even in background mode).
Answer upvoted & accepted..